# What is the template code for order date and telephone number

Tags: commerce

In our invoice that is printed, the date of the order and the telephone of the customer is missing. How can I print those into the template?

Answer (score 1):

Using `{{ invoice_entity.orders.0 }}` you get access to the order.

So if you're looking to print the order completed time you'd need something like:

`{{ invoice_entity.orders.0.getCompletedTime }}` which is a timestamp. You'd need getPlacedTime in case you need access to the placed timestamp.

For the telephone, where is that stored? On the profile itself?

```
{{ invoice_entity.getBillingProfile.(your phone field name here I suppose) }}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140166/discussion-on-answer-by-jonathan-sacksick-what-is-the-template-code-for-order-da).